# callback is not a function in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying a simple operation that will result the particular users details from the database. Pooling database and all other connections work perfectly but the callback is not working. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Below is the code I use.

db_crud.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var crud = require('./routes/crud_op_new.js');
var search = require('./routes/search.js');

var connection;
var result;
app.get('/search',(req,res)=>{
  crud.connection(function (con) {
    search.getuser(con,req.param('name'),result);
    res.send(result);
  });
});
app.listen(8003);
```

Finally here is where the error occurs ... search.js

```
exports.getuser = function(connection,req,callback){
console.log("GET Request iniciated");
connection.query("select * from user,addr where name=? and user.id=addr.e_id",[req],(err,row)=>{
 if(err){
    callback("DB ERROR: "+err);
 }
 else {
   if(row.length==0){
   callback("No Records found");
  }
   else {
    callback(row);
   }
  }
 });
}
```

The `db_crud` will send the credentials to search.js and here the callback is called to send result. crud_op_new.js creates the db pool connection and is in variable con.

Comment: you call your function `search.getuser(con,req.param('name'),result);` ... `result` is not a function, it's undefined ... a callback needs to be a function so it can be called back

Comment: I get it. but how do i add the function callback in my logic ?

Comment: I've added an answer that should help

Comment: Also, the `callback` is being returned the error and result both in the first argument. Change this `callback(row);` to `callback(null, row);` and handle the same in the calling method.

Comment: I have used a logic simillar to this ... var sum1 = function (a,b, callback){
    callback(a + b);
};

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by [Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) in the answer, `result` is just declared and unassigned which should be a callback `function`.

Also, the callback in `search.js` is being returned the `error` and `result` both as the first argument. You have to change this `callback(row)` to `callback(null, row)` to handle the error and result as below.

> Note: Best practice in `node js` callback function would be, first argument
>   should return an error (*null* in case of no error) and then remaining arguments can be the return
>   values.

**db_crud.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var crud = require('./routes/crud_op_new.js');
var search = require('./routes/search.js');

var connection;

app.get('/search',(req,res)=>{
  crud.connection(function (con) {
    search.getuser(con,req.param('name'), function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
         res.status(501).send(err);
      } else {
        res.send(result);
      }
    });
  });
});
app.listen(8003);
```

**search.js**

```
exports.getuser = function(connection,req,callback){
console.log("GET Request iniciated");
connection.query("select * from user,addr where name=? and user.id=addr.e_id",[req],(err,row)=>{
 if(err){
    callback("DB ERROR: "+err);
 }
 else {
   if(row.length==0){
   callback("No Records found");
  }
   else {
    callback(null, row);
   }
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: Will this not effect the eirler callback i used where i pass only one argument !!!

Comment: It won't since its passing the `err` argument and there is a check in `db_crud.js` for `if(err) { }`

Answer (score 3):

you call your function `search.getuser(con,req.param('name'),result);` ... `result` is not a function, it's undefined ... a callback needs to be a function so it can be called back

This should work

```
app.get('/search',(req,res)=>{
  crud.connection(function (con) {
    //                                   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv this is the callback function
    search.getuser(con,req.param('name'),function(result) {
      res.send(result);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Ohh now i get it !! Thats it ... I got the callback logic ... Thanks